# Python3.9 flask apache 2.4 modwsgi gives RuntimeError: fork not supported for subinterpreters

Tags: apache, flask, multiprocessing, mod-wsgi, python-3.9

I am trying to run code with python 3.9, flask, wsgi and using multiprocessing.

Hitting this issue.

```
[03/09/2021 09:35:44 AM] ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ibm/tornado/flask/controllers/default_controller.py", line 151, in _wrapper_build
    _build(new_db_conn, bom, logger=api_logger, transaction_id=transaction_id)
  File "/opt/ibm/tornado/flask/controllers/default_controller.py", line 305, in _build
    vcenterutils.increase_vum_mm_timeout(logger=logger)
  File "/opt/ibm/tornado/utils/vcenterutils.py", line 2181, in increase_vum_mm_timeout
    child = pexpect.spawn(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 205, in __init__
    self._spawn(command, args, preexec_fn, dimensions)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 303, in _spawn
    self.ptyproc = self._spawnpty(self.args, env=self.env,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 315, in _spawnpty
    return ptyprocess.PtyProcess.spawn(args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ptyprocess/ptyprocess.py", line 230, in spawn
    pid, fd = pty.fork()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/pty.py", line 85, in fork
    pid, fd = os.forkpty()
  RuntimeError: fork not supported for subinterpreters
```

Here are my .conf and .wsgi files

tornado.conf

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:443 https
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName localhost

    ErrorLog /var/log/ibm/tornado/error_log
    LoadModule wsgi_module "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py39.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/flask/tornado.wsgi
    WSGIDaemonProcess processes=6 threads=10
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/server.key
    <Directory /opt/ibm/tornado/flask>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

tornado.wsgi

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.9
import os
import sys
import connexion

sys.path.append('/opt/ibm/tornado/flask')
sys.path.append('/opt/ibm/tornado/flask/controllers')

os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages:/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload:/usr/local/lib/python3.9'
os.environ['PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY'] = '0'
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/usr/local/lib'

app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir='/opt/ibm/tornado/flask/swagger/')
app.add_api('swagger.yaml')
application = app.app
```

This issue is very similar to this one [python 3.8 flask apache 2.4 wsgi multiprocessing RuntimeError: fork not supported for subinterpreters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63861363/python-3-8-flask-apache-2-4-wsgi-multiprocessing-runtimeerror-fork-not-supporte) but I already tried the workaround mentioned in there and still hitting the same issue. Any ideas?